# The attribute 'children_' of Agglomerative clustering

Tags: hierarchical-clustering

I am writing a very basic program with observations not exceeding 20 values (X1 is the original dateset).

```
X1_test=X1_df.iloc[0:20,]
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering

ag= AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=6, affinity= 'euclidean', linkage='ward', compute_full_tree= True, compute_distances=True)

ag.fit(X1_test)

When I run the attribute ag.chilren_ the values come as 

array([[10, 13],
       [ 1,  6],
       [16, 18],
       [ 2, 19],
       [ 4, 20],
       [ 8, 15],
       [12, 23],
       [14, 21],
       [ 0, 17],
       [ 9, 26],
       [22, 27],
       [11, 24],
       [ 5, 29],
       [ 7, 25],
       [ 3, 28],
       [30, 31],
       [32, 35],
       [33, 36],
       [34, 37]], dtype=int64)
```

how come values in this output are coming more than 20 since i have only 20 observations?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

According to what I can understand from reading [Scikit-learn's documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html), each array represents a node that has two values. If the value is smaller than your sample size, it represents a leaf and you can therefore consider its value to be the sample index. But if the value is bigger or equal to your sample size than this is not a leaf, it is a different node (that merged earlier). Which node is it? The node that is stored in index [value - n_samples] in the children_ attribute.
So for example, if your sample size is 20 and you have a node that merges 3 with 28, you can understand that 3 is the leaf of your third sample and 28 is the node of children_[8] (because 28-20=8). So it will be the node of [14, 21] in your case.